# Passing arguments by reference and Pointers in c

Tags: c

I have the following code-

```
#include <stdio.h>

void changeData(int * ax,int * ay)
{
    ax=ay;
    *ay=0;
    *ax=*ax+*ay;
}

int main()
{
    int x=13;
    int y=21;

    changeData(&x,&y);

    printf("x: %d\n",x );

}
```

Since I am doing `ax=ay` , so `ax=21`, then `*ax=21+0=21`
So, the answer printed should be `21`. But I get `x=13` as output. Why is it so?

Comment: because this line  *ay=0;  you do this *ax = *ax + 0; actually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C does not support pass by reference, strictly speaking.  You can pass the value of a variables address and dereference that value.

Your function changes the local variable `ax` to hold the same value as `ay`, namely the address of `y` in main.  At this point, no variable in this function contains the address of `x` in main so it cannot be modified.

The next line in `changeData` dereferences `ay` and sets the value at that address (i.e. `y` in main) to 0.  The third line then dereferences `ax` which currently contains the address of `y`, not `x`, and sets it to the value `ax` points to (`y` in main which contains 0) plus the value `ay` points to (again, `y` in main which is 0).

When the function returns, `x` is unchanged and thus the `printf` outputs 13.  If you were to print `y` as well, you would see it is 0.

Answer (score 2):

The answer printed would be `21` if you had used `*ax = *ay;` instead of `ax = ay`.

---

Why are you getting `13` as result?

When you call `ChangeData(&x, &y);`, what you are doing is you are passing the `addresses` of `x` and `y` to `ChangeDaata`.

Now, in `ChangeData()`, `ax` will have the address of `x`, and `ay` will have to address of `y`.

When you do `ax = ay;`, what happens is that `ax` will be equal to `ay`. So from that point onwards `ax` will have the address of `y`. Now whatever you do to `*ax` will change the value of `y`, and *NOT* `x` - as you were incorrectly expecting. i.e. When you do `*ax=*ax+*ay;`, it will change value of `y` - not value of `x`.

So, you see that value of `x` was never changed: as seen in the output of your `printf` statment. Print the value of `y` and you can see that its value will be chnged.